# How to configure and use Grunt for SAPUI5?

Tags: performance, gruntjs, sapui5

I was looking into this blog -

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/02/19/sapui5openui5-performance

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/02/18/optimizing-openui5-apps

But unable to understand how Grunt can be configured and used for my SAPUI5 application to increase the performance?

Can someone post a simple steps what should be followed?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: What is your exact issue? The `openui5_preload` Grunt task from https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5 minimizes and bundles your project files into a single Component-preload file, so you don't have multiple requests to retrieve the various files

Comment: There is no issue - I have my SAPUi5 app ready - Now I need to improve the performance so need to understand - How can I use GRUNT-OpenUi5 tool. Need a step by step procedure to do so as I am not able to understand from mentioned links

Comment: But it's there on the Github page... you install grunt (`npm install -g grunt-cli`), you install grunt-openiu5 (`npm install grunt-openui5`), and in your UI5 gruntfile, you add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-openui5');`. You then run `grunt openui5_preload` from your UI5 project root. If you're new to Grunt, see the Getting Started page http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: @Rahul were you able to configure grunt for SAPUI5?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite: you use Eclipse
You add Eclipse TM Terminal plugin
You install Node.js
Then select your project folder, press "Ctrl+Alt+T" to open terminal positioned to project folder.
perform command npm install grunt-openui5 --save-dev
Then you have to create in your project root folder file Gruntfile.js
You need to learn a little here how to configure this file, but it will not take more than hour of your time.
And after you configure this task, you run command "grunt" in your terminal

Comment: How it relate with the question?